# How can I overload autocompletion to work with full contexts?

Tags: front-end, keyboard, autocomplete

I would like for the autocomplete feature to search through contexts, for example if I have a symbol named A`B`C`MyFunction, when I type A` and press "cmd + shift + k" it will complete it.

*Edit*

To be clear, I don't want to have to type the path because it's usually very long, and I don't want to have to type the function name again, even if the path itself gets auto completed. I want the following:

If I have these functions:

```
Very`Long`Context`For`My`Function1
Very`Long`Context`For`My`Function2
...
```

I want to be able to type Very` and then press CMD+Shift+k, to get a dropdown menu saying exactly

```
Very`Long`Context`For`My`Function1
Very`Long`Context`For`My`Function2
...
```

Comment: I assume you mean `cmd-k`, since `cmd-shift-k` inserts a template.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ***This is obsolete in Mathematica 9, which automatically includes contexts in completions.***
>
> ***Undocumented function: use at your own risk, subject to change in future versions, etc....***

---

The function you're interested in is `` FE`FC ``.

It's been around for a while (here's a [Mathematica Journal article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v6i3/columns/wagner/contents/63wagner.pdf) that references it, near the end) although it has changed argument structure at least once that I'm aware of.

Anyway, here's the code I currently use to a similar end as what Mike would like.  (Most of this is boilerplate from the original definition; the main difference is the use of a new function `` FE`names ``.)

```
(* Nice little hack to have command completion (cmd-k) include contexts *)
Unprotect[FE`FC];
ClearAll[FE`FC]

FE`FC[FE`nameString_, FE`ignoreCase_:False] /; $Notebooks:=
    MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`CompletionsListPacket[
        FE`names[FE`nameString<>"*"], FE`ignoreCase],
        FE`NoResult]

FE`names[FE`str_, FE`ignoreCase_:False] :=
    Join[FE`shortContexts[FE`str], Names[FE`str, IgnoreCase -> FE`ignoreCase]];

FE`shortContexts[FE`patt_]:=
 With[{FE`brettclen = Length[StringSplit[FE`patt, "`"]]},
  Union[StringJoin[
      Riffle[Take[#, Min[FE`brettclen, Length[#]]], "`", {2, -1, 2}]] & /@
    StringSplit[Contexts[FE`patt], "`"]]
  ]
    
Protect[FE`FC];
```

The end result is that when I use command completion, I get contexts that match in addition to symbols.  This isn't quite the same as Mike's request, since it gives the contexts one at a time:

[image]

[image]

since otherwise the list can get a bit overwhelming.  For example, if you typed `Int` and then tried to complete to `IntegerPart`, there's a factor of ten difference:

```
In[5]:= {Length[Names["Int*"]] + Length[Contexts["Int*"]], 
 Length[Names["Int*`*"]]}

Out[5]= {41, 419}
```

Comment: wow, I have somehow missed autocomplete for the last 5 years.... thanks for this!

Comment: Exactly! I knew I wasn't crazy.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to put the context on the path:

```
$ContextPath = AppendTo[$ContextPath, "A`B`C`"]
```

Comment: I don't think this works. After appending to the $ContextPath, if you type "CMD+Shift+k", after typing "A\`", you don't get a list with A`B`C`(functions) as items to complete, as you would if you typed "MapThre"...

Comment: @Mike, expanding MyF+Shift+k works just fine. If you want something else, I suggest to state that more clearly in your question.

Comment: @Mike, just that we are on the same page: adding A`B`C`MyFunction
A`B`C`MyFunction2 give a list of items. Maybe I don't get what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I just updated the question a bit.