# Enhanced "Complete Selection" (dynamic autocomplete) for Text input?

Tags: front-end, keyboard

The autocomplete ("Complete Selection") feature <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd> on Windows) works fine for functions and code input.

Is there a way to enhance it for text input?

Today’s standard (see e.g. OpenOffice etc.) is to autocomplete based on words already occuring in the text.

For text *Mathematica* will just display words from a (very simple) dictionary.
If I type e.g. "Grav" it will show "Grave", "Gravy" etc. It does not even seem to know "Gravity" or "Gravitation" (despite these being common words and despite occurences in my text)

Comment: have you seen this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6842/169 and the reference therein?  I think it is the closest if you want full control over the auto-completion mechanism. That stuff is undocumented, unsupported, and really low level. And I  can't see whether it would be possible to really do what you want but suspect it might be...

Comment: I have just played around with that and now think that the autocompletion for text unlike that for input doesn't even go through the kernel, which probably leaves you with what Verbeia has suggested...

Answer (score 11):

Actually, *Mathematica* does know these words, but requires a bit of prodding to suggest them.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

You can add additional word suggestions via the Options Inspector, but I don't think there is a general way to customize the ordering of the words that appear in the suggestions popup menu.

[image]

Comment: Thx for the hint. So we would rather have to **take away** words than add new ones. The sorting is really strange, as you show in your screenshot.

Comment: Adding suggestions (which then appear first in the list) works sometimes, but only after fiddling around with other options (Language Category), restarting? I cannot reproduce it.
Anyway it is not an option to add a myriad of suggestions by hand.