# Custom (physics) dictionary for mathematica (used for word-processing, spell checking)

Tags: front-end

Is there a dictonary available that contains physics slang like spinor, vacua, gauge etc.??

How would one integrate such a file (or a simple text file containing the words) into the front-end without too much of a hassle?

Comment: How is this *Mathematica*-related? (the -1 is not mine, FWIW)

Comment: Have a look at `DictionaryLookup`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks, surprisingly, even OP's third example is not known to `DictionaryLookup[]`... I had thought it wasn't a very specialized word that it had to be there, but it isn't.

Comment: guys, keep the snark, the sharks and other things at home please!
This question is MMA-related for anyone using it as a word-processor. It is also related to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13134/enhanced-complete-selection-dynamic-autocomplete-for-text-input

Comment: @NoEscape -- no snark from me, but I still don't see how this is *Mathematica*-specific.  There are many word lists on the web, e.g. YAWL or ENABLE2K.  Perhaps you would do better to ask how a new dictionary can be integrated into *Mathematica*?

Comment: @J.M. I'm not surprised but I think it's just fun to stare at words I've never heard of. That's the only usage of that command for me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard : The intent was - indeed - that such a dictionary would come with an installation readme. I edited the question, though.

Comment: @NoEscape I'd edit the question to highlight that you're using MMA for word-processing, and need a custom dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

One way you could do this is to add the words to your `init.m` file.

```
SpellingDictionaries->{"CorrectWords"->
 {"gauge", "spinor", "muon", "tauon"}},
```

[image: macvim]

which has the same effect as adding them using the 'Learn' button on the Spelling panel, I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

The closest i can think of is some combination of

```
In[44]:= WordData["spinor"] // InputForm
WordData["gauge"] // InputForm

Out[45]//InputForm=
{{"gauge", "Noun", "MeasuringInstrument"}, {"gauge", "Noun", "Diameter"}, 
 {"gauge", "Noun", "Thickness"}, {"gauge", "Noun", "Distance"}, 
 {"gauge", "Noun", "Standard"}, {"gauge", "Verb", "Flux"}, 
 {"gauge", "Verb", "Standardize"}, {"gauge", "Verb", "Measure"}, 
 {"gauge", "Verb", "Figure"}, {"gauge", "Verb", "Determine"}, {"gauge", "Verb", "Rub"}}

In[46]:= DictionaryLookup["spinor"]
DictionaryLookup["spin"]

Out[46]= {}

Out[47]= {"spin"}

In[50]:= WolframAlpha["spinor", {{"Input", 1}, "Plaintext"}] // InputForm

Out[50]//InputForm=
"spinor"
```

If all of these don't return `{}`, then your word is hopefully confirmed correct spelling.