# How to extend dictionary.txt?

Tags: string-manipulation, curated-data

How to extend the default dictionary.txt for `Dictionarylookup` to all words?

For example, first I

```
wordsExtended=WordData[]~Join~DictionaryLookup["*"]//Union;
wordsExtended//Length
```

However, after reloading the dictionary.txt some words are omitted, for example:

```
In[73]:= DictionaryLookup["appals"]
Out[73]= {}
In[74]:= WordData["appals"]
Out[74]= {{appal,Verb,Frighten},{appal,Verb,Nauseate}}
```

How to add all such words like #appals# to dictionary.txt?

One method: Tuples to create a word verified by WordData, which takes too much time. For

```
In[78]:= Binomial[26,7]
Out[78]= 657800
```

Second method:

```
listAlls = # <> "s" & /@ DictionaryLookup["*"];
wordsToExport = Select[listAlls, Length[WordData@#] > 1 &];
In[81]:= Complement[wordsToExport,DictionaryLookup["*"]]//Length
Out[81]= 2580
```

I get 2580 new words for dictionary.txt, but how to get all prefix and suffix such like `s` `pre` `es`... and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13142/5

Comment: @rm-rf ha,I saw one WolframAlpha["appals", {{"Input", 1}, "Plaintext"}] return "appalls  (English word)"

Comment: 'appals' might be the US spelling, 'appalls' the British...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve all of the inflected forms of words (plurals, conjugations, etc) that WordData knows with:

```
DeleteDuplicates@
 Flatten[WordData[#, "InflectedForms"][[All, 2]] & /@ WordData[]]
```

Comment: do you know how to obtain all the prefix or suffix, can it be retrieved form WordData?

Comment: Well not all inflections in English consist of just adding a prefix or suffix. The rules are more consistent if you look at phonology as opposed to spelling, for example, berry->berries. A few English grammar Wikipedia articles probably contain enough information to meet your needs for common prefixes and suffixes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural