# Is it Possible to create my own Dictionary?

Tags: customization, dictionary

When I count the number of words in the English dictionary

```
wordsInLanguage[lang_] := {lang, Length[DictionaryLookup[{lang, All}]]}
wordsInLanguage["English"]
```

it says there are only 92 518 words.

Is it possible to insert my own words into the dictionary? Or will it work if I put my own mydictionary.txt in the Dictionaries folder and are there any drawbacks in doing so? How about spelling and hyphenation?

Comment: @Pickett Thanks for the corrections...My English are terrible!

Comment: Partial duplicate: [(13142)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13142/121)

Comment: @Mr Wizard Is not a good idea to enter thousands of words in init.m. Also, I am looking a general solution that enables me to insert any dictionary (medicine, Physics, non latin languages...) Thanks for the link

Comment: @kornaros if you still want this, you could have init.m import the words from a dict extension file you keep somewhere. Like add `SpellingDictionaries->Import["somepath/dictExtension.m"]` to the init.m file.