# Is it possible to improve Mathematica's auto-completion feature?

Tags: front-end, version-9, autocomplete

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6842/187) Brett Champion describes how one can intercept and modify the suggestions used for auto-completion.

**Question:** Is it possible to modify the suggestion for the automatic auto-completion in *Mathematica* version 9?

### Background

I think it's possible to improve the auto-completion significantly by using *camel humps completion*. If you want to see it in action, I made a small screen-cast to demonstrate it for *Mathematica* **version 8** (please switch to 
1080p and fullscreen):

[image]

- <strike>For all users from good old Germany or</strike> for users who prefer classical music: here is a <strike>GEMA friendly,</strike> [musically educating version](http://youtu.be/iIG8_Pmzjn0).
- Users from Germany can enjoy this screen-cast in [comforting silence!](http://youtu.be/mzFfNbl9sr4)

The basic idea is to

- allow `ListLiPlo`, `ListLPlot` or even `LLP` to be expanded to `ListLinePlot`. Since all *Mathematica* built-in functions are consistently named, this works pretty well
- to sort the list of suggestions by importance. In the screencast, I used the appearance of built-in functions in all packages of the `AddOns` directory as measure. The more often a function was used, the more likely it is to be on top of the list if it matches. To give an example: When you expand `Pl` in version 8, you get a list consisting of `Placed`, `Placeholder`, `PlaceholderRepeated`, `Plain`, `Play`, ... Those are all functions I barely use. I the auto-expansion I wrote, `Plot`, `PlotRange` and `Plus` are on the top of the list and after them all the others follow. In version 9 this was fixed and the completion box seems to have a better ordering.

Comment: A giant +1 for the screen-cast alone:) BTW did you post the "camel humps completion" code anywhere?

Comment: @Ajasja Thanks. I haven't posted the code yet since it is neither finished nor polished.

Comment: From the docs "Completion suggestions are intelligently and automatically prioritized, based in part on your usage patterns and the context in which you are coding.". So the order of appearance issue seems to be already there

Comment: Great idea! +1 It reminds me the short-cut interface in Sublime Text.

Comment: @Rojo I tried it in version 8, where this is not the case. Please see my update in the last item.

Comment: I get a funny (if not amusing) GEMA message: "Dieses Video enthält Content von UMG. Dieser Partner hat das Video in deinem Land aus urheberrechtlichen Gründen gesperrt."

Comment: Not enough Rammstein in the video...

Comment: @YvesKlett Yes, I already have someone here from UMG arresting me.. Give me some minutes. I re-code the video with GEMA compatible content..

Comment: now the classical version is also unavailable (in DE). Is this automatically done? Maybe you should produce a version where you the musical background is provided by you singing or something?

Comment: acl See my update. Unbelievable. I thought that between the thousands of interpretations of Liszts *La Campanella* (and since the composer is dead since 1886) it's maybe OK to use it as background music. Obviously not! Music is no longer allowed in Germany. Please write a thank you email to gema@gema.de

Comment: Did you notice that there is a Front End option called `CamelCaseMatchScore`?  Search for `Match` in the option inspector.

Comment: This seems to have made it into built-in funcitonality in v13.3, with "fuzzy autocompletion of symbols", described in the [Autocomplete Symbols When Typing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/AutocompleteSymbolsWhenTyping.html) documentation.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## Preface

With *Mathematica* version **9.0.1** the following answer not valid anymore because the underlying protocol between front end and kernel was changed. Fortunately, we started to implement an open-source *Mathematica* plugin for IntelliJIDEA which has a full support for camel-hump completion.

**[Please see this post for more information](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24556/187)**

## Camel-humps auto-completion for Mathematica

The answer to my question is yes, we can expand the auto-completion capabilities of *Mathematica*. For those who want to know, how exactly this can be done, I suggest reading the *Reverse engineering* section below. There I explained how you can investigate in the default completion in *Mathematica* and how you can modify its behavior.

For all those who cannot wait to test it: A simple `Get` of my package from [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/halirutan/MathematicaAutocompletionTweaker) turns the camel-humps completion on:

```
Get["http://goo.gl/wtVze"]
```

In Mathematica 9 you should now see a suggestion box when you type e.g. `PP`. If you want to turn it off again can simply restart the kernel or you use `` FE`RecoverDefaultCompletion[] ``. If you want to install it permanently you can for instance copy the contents of the package to your `init.m`.

### Usage

To be really fast with this kind of help you have to try avoiding arrow-keys for going down the suggestion list. Instead, you should specify your wanted function further and further by leaving out the small letters between capital camel-hump letters. A very good example is `Hypergeometric0F1`. Instead of typing `Hy` and going down the list very far, you leave out 12 letters and type `Hy0`. In many, many cases this leads to only one unique choice of an expansion and you only have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Tab</kbd>) to accept it.

If there are still several choices in the end, *then* you can use your arrow keys. One example here is, when you typed (heroically) `LLLP` to shorten `ListLogLinearPlot` and see that there is a `ListLogLogPlot` with the same abbreviation. Unfortunately, at this point even typing `LLLPlot` does not help to make it clear and you have to use the arrow key to choose the right function.

Let me show you, what works and how it works.
**Completion of usual function names** works now both ways:

1. You get valid expansions if you type a *prefix* of the function like `Integ` for `IntegerDigits`.
2. Additionally, you can type `IntDig`, `InDi` or just `ID` to get `IntegerDigits` too. Important is that you take care of the capital letters in the names.

> [image]

Support for **completion of `Options`** was added too.

> [image]

Additionally, camel-humps even work **after context specifications**. Note, that the context-names themselves cannot be camel-humps expanded because in most cases like `Developer`, `Experimental`, `Internal`, etc. this would be useless anyway.

> [image]

## How it was reverse-engineered

Let me explain in detail how you can investigate into how the auto-completion works. What I used is the [*JLink* Link Snooper](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/JLink/ref/java/com/wolfram/jlink/util/LinkSnooper.html). With this you don't start the *Mathematica* kernel as usual. Instead a special *JLink* program listens and prints the communication between front-end and kernel.

The installation is straight forward: You go to *Evaluation*->*Kernel Configuration Options* and create a new kernel exactly as described in the documentation to `LinkSnooper` I linked above. Then you set either *Default Kernel* or the *Notebook Kernel* (in the *Evaluation* menu) to the `LinkSnooper` and restart the kernel. A java window pops up showing you all traffic. When the message-war of the initialisation is over you can clear the window and then type for instance `Pl` and you see that at this very moment the front-end sends a packet to the kernel. The `LinkSnooper` tells me

```
System`EvaluatePacket[FrontEnd`SynchronousDynamicEvaluate[TimeConstrained[
   FE`CAFC["Pl", False]
    , 6.0], 0, 9.0, 0.2563962936401367]]
```

The important line is of course the second one. Here you see, that the function `` FE`CAFC `` is called. Let's have a look a the implementation (I killed all context prefixes in the output):

```
??FE`CAFC

CAFC[nameString_,ignoreCase_:False]/;$Notebooks:=
  MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`CompletionsListPacket[
   nameString,
   Names[nameString<>"*",IgnoreCase->ignoreCase],
   Contexts["*"<>(nameString<>"*")]
  ],NoResult]
```

The kernel sends a `CompletionListPacket` to the front-end which has 3 parameters.  As far as I could find out they mean the following:

1. `nameString` is not only a repetition of the input-string! This is used as filter. So when `Pl` is expanded and the list of suggestions (the second parameter) would contain the word `BarbieAndKen` the front-end won't show this in the choice-box, because `Barbie..` does not match `Pl...`. This is important for our camel hump expansion, because we try to expand something like `LLP` to `ListLinePlot`. The solution here is to take only the first letter of the input-string which will hopefully always match. So if I try to expand `LLP` and I give `ListLinePlot` in my suggestions list, then the `L...` will match and `ListLinePlot` is displayed in the suggestion box.
2. The second parameter is simply a list of suggestions which are displayed if they match the first parameter. Currently, only all matching names are displayed. We will extend this, so that we calculate possible function-names from camel hump shorties.
3. This is the list of possible matching context names.

### How options-matching works

Unfortunately, the matching of options seems to works differently. Here, *Mathematica* uses the syntax information of the function to decide whether you are on a possible option position. Here are two equivalent calls:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[Sequence[x, {x, 0, 1}]]
```

If you now go behind the closing curly braces of each example, make a comma and type `Pl` you shouldn't be too surprised that the first list contains all options, where the second choice-box contains usual function. If you check the output of the `LoopSnooper`, then you see that only in the first case the function `` FE`OC["Plot", "Pl"] `` is called. This is the option-completion function and it looks like

```
OC[nameString_,patternString_]/;$Notebooks:=
  MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`OptionCompletionsListPacket[
    nameString,
    patternString,
    (ToString[#1]&)/@(InputForm[#1]&)/@
      Options[ToExpression[nameString]]],
  NoResult]
```

See, that here a `OptionCompletionsListPacket` is send to the front-end. Therefore, the front-end handles options-expansion differently. For the moment I will not touch this, because I haven't tested the stuff, but I will. What you should see here is, that our camel hump expansion will currently only work on function names and not, when you are inside a function at an option-position.

### Implementation

Here are the important details of the following lines. First, I will import the file with the function informations of all *Mathematica* functions. This contains function names, call patterns and template constructs, but I will only use the function names. The difference to a call to `Names` is, that this contains the function names only and not some options. For the current purpose this is maybe better.

The next one-liner is maybe the most important function:

```
nameParts[in_String] := StringCases[in, _?(UpperCaseQ[#] || DigitQ[#] &) ~~ ___?LowerCaseQ];
```

This has the purpose to split a *Mathematica*-style function name into its parts. When a capital letter is seen, a new part starts

```
nameParts["ListPointPlot3D"]

(* {"List", "Point", "Plot", "3", "D"} *)
```

What you could do is, you take from every part as many lower case letters as you want from the back and put it back together and you have a valid, expandable camel hump short-cut. Important is, that such a word-part starts always with a capital letter and is followed only by lower-case letters. Numbers are like capital letters.
This is then used in the `getMatch` function. There, we take some input and calculate all possible function expansions by using the name-parts to create a regular expression.

Then we implant this into the `` FE`CAFC `` function and after executing this, the advanced expansion should work. So typing `FiAM` for instance gives

[image]

The complete implementation can be found on [my GitHub site](https://github.com/halirutan/MathematicaAutocompletionTweaker)

### Known issues and limitations and bug-report

To **report bugs or unusual behavior** please use [the issues section here](https://github.com/halirutan/MathematicaAutocompletionTweaker/issues).

- The front-end does not call on every keystroke the auto-completion function. You can watch this on the `LinkSnooper`. This means for instance, that you won't get a choice box when you type `FAM`, although `FindArgMin` matches. Our function is simply not called. What you can do is type another `i` or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>.
- On Linux there seems to be a bug regarding the above point: When you type `Pl` and close the appearing suggestion-box with <kbd>Esc</kbd> it is not possible to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to reopen this box. Using arrow-keys to move around and going then to the same place and it works.
- jensbob [reported](https://github.com/halirutan/MathematicaAutocompletionTweaker/issues/1) that a message was generated about *Throwing False* when the code is put into `init.m`. This issue is fixed and was not related to the autocompletion code itself.
- sebhofer asked in the comments: *Would it in principle be possible to get completion similar to most shells where hitting tab completes to the longest common sequence and not to the first match?* Answer: In principal yes, but there's a very big *but* attached to this. In version 8 where you have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for expansion the suggestion-box shows the entries exactly in the same order as I supply it (at least in Linux!). Here, the thing you would have to implement is the calculation of the longest common sequence and then you prepend it to the list of suggestions you return. Then this is always on top of of list and you can simply expand it always. In version 9 the list of suggestions is sorted by the FE (front end) and I don't know how to influence the ordering. This all happens inside the FE where you have not really a chance to re-engineer what happens. The only possibility I see here is to supply the longest common sequence as *only* suggestion when it exists. One problem in both versions is that the FE closes the suggestion and don't asks the kernel again whether there exist more possible expansions because it believes you already found the function you like to have. You can test this: type `Plo` and you see the `Plot` is LCS here. Accepting this closes the window and you would have to type another letter or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to reopen it. I don't think this is a good idea.
- 18/01/2013 I forgot to include `$` as separator and therefore variables like `$KernelID` can not be shortened by e.g. `$KID`. Furthermore, I think about adding symbols in the `` Global` `` which don't start with a capital letter. In this way it's possible to expand user-defined symbols too.

Comment: I didn't have time to read this yet, but my biggest wish is for file name completion.  Is it (theoretically) possible using this method?

Comment: @Szabolcs You have to see that it's not getting too slow, but theoretically you can return whatever suggestion you think. We have to test though how it works inside strings, because filenames are always string and you may want to expand it there. Which files do you want to expand? All on the file-system or can you narrow it down?

Comment: Something similar to what matlab does would be useful: expand only in strings and use the whole file system: check if the portion of the string entered could be a file/path (assuming a path relative to the current directory) and if yes, expand.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry, but the output of the linksnooper shows, that when I try to expand `"Hello`, I only get the `Hello` and therefore, I don't know whether I'm in a string expression.

Comment: Oh that's a pity ... what if you type `"~/somedir/somefile`?  Does it return `somefile` only or the full path together with `~`?

Comment: Oh, I would be so interested to see how this works in Linux! I guess I could figure it out following your instructions from above, but if you have existing code, could you share it?

Comment: @sebhofer Patience! I update the post in a few hours with complete support for Linux, OSX and Windows.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code! Would it in principle be possible to get completion similar to most shells where hitting tab completes to the longest common sequence and not to the first match? (I know this is a bit different from what you are doing now, as then you would only search for matches starting with the given string.)

Comment: Ignore what follows this sentence, as I found `LinkSnooper.jar` in `SystemFiles/Links/JLink/Source/Java/com/wolfram.jlink/util`. Where does one obtain the `LinkSnooper` `JLink` `LinkSnooper`? I don't find it within the Mathematica distribution, and the page http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/JLink/ref/java/com/wolfram/jlink/util/LinkSnooper.html does not seem to provide a link but says this documentation is for an obsolete product.

Comment: @murray To set up a link-snooper kernel, you only need `JLink.jar` since the LinkSnooper classes in this package. The rest is only to follow the documentation I linked and modify the paths according to your system.

Comment: This is so cool! Is there currently a way to get camel hump autocompletion from within Mathematica 9.0.1 (or something that can run the language)?

Comment: @episanty Unfortunately you won't get camel humps in the *Mathematica* front end and with 9.0.1 it is no longer possible to use my hack. I have build all the fancy features (and many more than only camel humps) into the [IntelliJ IDEA plugin](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24556/187). Note that IDEA is an IDE, not the front end where you can evaluate stuff, create graphics, etc.. but in IDEA you can very comfortably code in the *Wolfram Language*

Comment: Has any attempt been made to get this working in version 10?  I know you you have moved on to IDEA but I still like the idea of using this in the Notebook interface.

Comment: @halirutan Did you see my question above?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Regarding my [responses](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan?tab=responses) tab, I must have been pinged by your comment, but somehow it seems I missed it. Sorry, it wasn't on purpose. If you like we can discuss this in chat and I tell you everything I know about it.

Comment: @halirutan I'll be right there.

Answer (score 14):

In the meantime, I was playing around. This is just to add a hotkey (<kbd>Alt+k</kbd> in windows) to replace what you have written so far with the partial symbol found. I don't know if it is a useful thing if we don't add it a way to handle multiple findings.

Put this in a "init.m" file, inside `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "AutocompleteBonus"}]`

```
BeginPackage["AutocompleteBonus`"]

CamelhumpExpand[] := With[{nb = InputNotebook[]}, 
  FrontEndTokenExecute["ExpandSelection"]; NotebookWrite[nb, 
    NotebookRead[nb] /. s_String :> With[{
        spatt=StartOfString~~StringReplace[s, b:Except[StartOfString]~~
              c_?UpperCaseQ :> b~~___?LowerCaseQ~~c]},
      With[{new = Names[spatt~~"*"]}, 
       StringCases[First[new], spatt, 1] /; new =!= {}]]]]

EndPackage[]
```

Now, add (backup first), in *MenuSetup.tr* which is in some subfolder in `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "TextResources"}]`, a line such as the following one

```
    MenuItem["Cameltoe E&xpand", FrontEnd`KernelExecute[Needs["AutocompleteBonus`"];AutocompleteBonus`CamelhumpExpand[]], MenuKey["k", Modifiers->{"Command"}],MenuEvaluator -> "System"],
```

right after (for example), the line that starts with `MenuItem["Complete Se&lection"`

Restart MMA, and test.

**EDIT**

@halirutan, failure, and gotta go. i was trying somethign along this lines, but as you suggested, dynamic

```
getCandidates[] := With[{nb = InputNotebook[]}, 
    FrontEndTokenExecute["ExpandSelection"]; 
      NotebookRead[nb] /. s_String :> With[{

      spatt = StartOfString ~~ 
        StringReplace[s, b : Except[StartOfString] ~~
                         (c_)?UpperCaseQ :> b ~~ ___?LowerCaseQ ~~ c]},
           With[{new = Names[spatt ~~ "*"]}, 
             new ]]]

suggestStuff[] := 
 MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`AttachCell[First@SelectedCells[],
   Cell[
    BoxData@ToBoxes@
      Row@
       Riffle[Button[#, NotebookWrite[First@SelectedCells[], #]] & /@ 
         getCandidates[], Spacer[20]]], "Inline", 
   "ClosingActions" -> {"SelectionDeparture", 
     "ParentChanged", "EvaluatorQuit"}]]
```

Now you write in a cell something like "LP", in a different cell evaluate `Pause[2];suggestStuff[]`, and you have 2 seconds to put your selection back after "LP"

Comment: Let me try this and combine it with my code. I have some more ideas which are maybe feasible or not. I'll try something. +1, although what we really should try to circumvent is continuously pressing some keys for completion ;-)

Comment: Where did you find `"Inline"` example?

Comment: @Kuba I have no idea, too long ago, sorry

Answer (score 12):

I'm using Mathematica 12.1 and I think the following feature was introduced in version 12.

You can add and execute the following code in your notebook:

```
(* the default value is Automatic *)
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {CodeAssistOptions, "MatchingAlgorithm"}] = "Fuzzy";
```

Source: YouTube [Wolfram Technology Conference 2019: Stephen Wolfram's Keynote Address](https://youtu.be/Slw_9h92aYI?t=8580) at 2h 23min.

With this option the Mathematica code completion becomes much better which can be seen below

[image: Mathematica fuzzy code completion]

[image: Mathematica fuzzy code completion LLP]