# How can autocomplete entries be added for DownValues and Properties?

Tags: front-end, customization, autocomplete

I'd like to assign `DownValues` to a symbol like this

```
x["firstvalue"] = 1;
x["secondvalue"] = 2;
```

And then have the `DownValue` keys `"firstvalue"` and `"secondvalue"` offered in an autocomplete list once I have entered `x[`.

Another useful application for this kind of modification is to have the `"Properties"` of an object like a `FittedModel` added to the autocomplete list.

It is not always easy to remember `"SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTableEntries"`, which is one of the 64 properties of `FittedModel`.

Can this be done? What controls the entries in the *autocomplete "engine"*?

#### Addendum

[This amazing answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16710/92) shows a way of altering the behavior of autocomplete. I do not yet understand how it works.

Comment: I can't answer the autocomplete question, but do you want a mechanism for automatically updating the properties list?

Comment: @rcollyer, I don't understand your question. I can always call `thisFit["Properties"]` to find the properties of the fit or `DownValues[x][[All,1,1,1]]` to get the keys of x. You have improvements upon these methods?

Comment: Not on `thisFit`, obviously. But, `DownValues[x][[All,1,1,1]]` is stymied by `fcn[] := `. So, I've been using `Case`, but you have to get the pattern correct.

Comment: Ah for this case I've added the `Keys` function from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/999/92) to my toolchain.

Comment: Well, that is far and away superior to my ad hoc solution. I may have to expropriate it ... :)

Comment: There is not much hope you achieve this with version 9.0.1. My answer you were referring to only works for 9.0. since back then the autocompletion was only partially done by the frontend. Nowadays, I don't see a way to interfere (let's call it *improve*) with the autocompletion happening in the *Mathematica* front end. In [my latest project](http://halirutan.de/start) this would be possible to implement, but it's not the front end.