# How to add symbols to autocompletion list

Tags: autocomplete

There are some built-in *Mathematica* symbols that I use quite frequently but are not included in the autocompletion list in the front end.  Examples are `Analytic` and `PolynomialForm`.  (As @march points out, `PolynomialForm` is present in version 9, but it's absent in version 10)

[image]

Is there a way to add these symbols to the autocompletion list?

Comment: As far as `PolynomialForm` goes, it's actually on the list when you hit the expand double arrow at the bottom.

Comment: @march It's there in version 9.1, but it's gone in version 10.2.  How do I bring it back on the list?

Comment: I don't readily have access at the moment to try it out, but perhaps a workaround might be to add the symbols in a different context that the autocomplete searches. Basically how the autocomplete finds functions defined in custom packages.

Comment: I have the same issue with AbsoluteTiming so when I'm testing I usually define a function like, `zAbsoluteTiming[x_] := AbsoluteTiming[x]` and it always pops up when you start typing "zA"

Comment: Check this out - http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16599/is-it-possible-to-improve-mathematicas-auto-completion-feature/16602#16602

Answer (score 3):

As for `Analytic` and `PolynomialForm`, they've been moved here:

```
FileNameJoin@{
  (* 
    Note that this is for v11.
    In v10 you need to find the FunctionalFrequency directory 
    *)
  PacletFind["AutoCompletionData"][[1]]["Location"],
  "Main",
  "internalFunctions.m"
  }
```

As I noted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151967/38205) these are functions that don't get added to the autocompletion list. You can remove them and restart and they'll autocomplete again.