# How do I add the infobutton in autocomplete that links to the documentation page for package functions?

Tags: front-end, documentation, button, autocomplete

When typing the name of a built-in function like `Integrate`, the button (*ℹ︎*) appears next to that name in the autocomplete:

[image]

But I don't get that (*ℹ︎*) button for my package functions, even though I have a help page for it that was made with Wolfram Workbench:

[image]

How do I add the info button to the autocompletion menu that links to the relevant documentation page for my package functions?

Comment: Something of interest (maybe?). JLink stuff has that but some built in packages e.g. GeneralUtilities do not. And it's not just that documented things have it, since I've definitely clicked the button and gotten a blank search page. E.g. `ExportPacket` has it but pops up nothing.

Comment: Look at `FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", 
  "AutoCompletionData", "Main", "documentedContexts.m"}`. I found that via `TextSearch` for `"JLink"` in the AutoCompletionData directory. Editing it allowed me to add the i for my own package (only works where there are searchable docs I think) but I couldn't get it to work a la `specialArgFunctions.tr` -- i.e. editable in my own package, not the file itself.

Answer (score 11):

So I mentioned this in a comment but I'll get it out here for the bounty poster too. Searching for the `` "JLink`" `` in the autocomplete directory gave me this:

```
FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", "AutoCompletionData", "Main", "documentedContexts.m"}
```

If we look at what's inside it:

```
FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", 
    "AutoCompletionData", "Main", "documentedContexts.m"} // 
  Import // NewlineateInput

{
 "System`",
 "ANOVA`",
 "BlackBodyRadiation`",
 "Compatibility`",
 "ComputerArithmetic`",
 "DatabaseLink`",
 "EquationTrekker`",
 "FiniteFields`",
 "JLink`",
 "NETLink`",
 "CUDALink`",
 "OpenCLLink`",
 "TetGenLink`",
 "RLink`",
 "CCodeGenerator`",
 "SymbolicC`",
 "NonlinearRegression`",
 "PhysicalConstants`",
 "PolyhedronOperations`",
 "Quaternions`",
 "ResonanceAbsorptionLines`",
 "StandardAtmosphere`",
 "VariationalMethods`",
 "LibraryLink`",
 "CCompilerDriver`",
 "Audio`",
 "FunctionApproximations`",
 "GUIKit`",
 "HierarchicalClustering`",
 "HypothesisTesting`",
 "MultivariateStatistics`",
 "Music`",
 "Notation`",
 "NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`",
 "StatisticalPlots`"
 }
```

I'll add something:

```
FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", 
    "AutoCompletionData", "Main", "documentedContexts.m"} // 
  Import // Last

"ChemTools`"
```

and we can see the i appears on reload:

[image: A wild i appears!]

Haven't figured out how to set this at the paclet level though, or even in [`$UserBaseDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$UserBaseDirectory.html).

Note that this is for 11

For 10 it seems the file is

```
FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
  "SystemResources", "FunctionalFrequency", "documentedContexts.m"}
```

---

Another cool file seems to be obsoleteFunctions.m which turns out to be a list of names to not autocomplete, even though they're in the language. I added [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html), restarted, and got this:

[image: no print :o]

Note that [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) is no longer completed by the FE.

There is also internalFunctions.m which has a similar effect. That contains things like `DeclareKnownSymbols`, and `AutoStyleOptions` which don't get autocompleted either, but I suppose are there because they're still used in the language.

Then there are the developerFunctions.m which are clearly contexts that don't get filled out by autocomplete (think `` NotebookTools`FlattenCellGroups `` -- `` NotebookTools` `` is in there).

Comment: thanks @b3m2a1, this is fantastic!  impressive detective work!   

I will add two bits for anyone who might come this way in the future:

Comment: (1) in my case, I needed to add a two-part path to `"documentedContexts.m"`, as in `MyApp\`MyPackage\``

Comment: (2) after I did this and restarted, I had the previously missing info icon, but it took me to a blank result in the documentation center.  To get the icon to actually link to my documentation, I had to rerun `BuildApplication["MyApp"]`.  

(I'm using jmlopez's ApplicationMaker project.  I'm not sure what the equivalent process would be otherwise.)

Comment: @billc  don't know what `BuildApplication` does as I have my own docs system, but I bet your docs weren't properly indexed. I'm gonna bet that i button just uses the same Command-F (on Mac) system which I think works via ``Documentation`HelpLookup`` which eventually dead ends on ``Documentation`ResolveLink``. So if ``Documentation`ResolveLink["MySym"]`` doesn't work the i button probably won't.

Comment: It's not currently possible to add to the DocumentedPath variable via paclets, but I have forwarded that suggestion to the relevant developer.  It should be relatively straightforward to add.

Comment: thanks @ItaiSeggev.  It would be great to have this supported as a first class feature, rather than something that needs to be set up by making (undocumented?) version-specific edits to system files.

Comment: Perhaps upon loading a package first time one can make a modification of the file: ``Export[FileNameJoin@{...}, Append[FileNameJoin@{...} // Import,"ChemTools`"]]``.  Do you know if that List of contexts is actually stored into a Symbol?  That way one can just test for its presence so that it is inserted only one time.

Comment: @QuantumDot I know nothing about how that system works, but I doubt it's stored anywhere at the top-level as digging for documentedContexts or any of those files has yielded 0.

Answer (score 0):

Very curious if there's been any progress on this.  It's now 2021, and I've built my own paclet application with documentation using Workbench 3 (Eclipse add-in 10.1.822) with MM 12.1.  Workbench is creating the index file but I get the same behavior as above for my own functions.

[image]

In addition, while the hover button double-chevron shows usage correctly, the info button is grayed out and does not link to my symbol documentation like the built-in functions do.

[image]

I have notice though, if I go ahead and evaluate this ?function line, it brings up the usage statement.  In the top right corner of the usage statement, there is an info button that actually works and actually links to my symbol page!

[image]

While this may not be an "answer", per se, it does show that the index is working to some limited degree and provides a work-around to getting to the desired ref/symbol page.

Comment: Better to post this useful information as a new question referencing the earlier question.