# linking usage message to package documentation

Tags: packages, documentation, workbench

I am trying to write documentation for a package I made, using Workbench. Let's say I have a function `test`, first I write a usage message as:

```
usage::test = "Description of test."
```

This is located in the .m file, outside of the private context.

Then using workbench I create a documentation page for this symbol.
Having done this, and after building the documentation and deploying the package, this documentation page for `test` is indeed accessible through the standard documentation menu by searching for `test`.

However, what I have been unable to do is to get a link to this page when evaluating `?test`, as the built-in functions have, something like:

```
?test
(*Description of test. >> *)
```

I have also tried with the [ApplicationMaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574710/integrating-notebooks-to-mathematicas-documentation-center) package, where it does work. However, before moving everything there I'd like to know if there's a simple fix for Workbench.

**edit:**
I've tried editing the PacletInfo.m, to read:

```
Paclet[
Name -> "testPackage",
Version -> "0.0.1",
MathematicaVersion -> "9+",

Extensions -> {
                {
                    "Kernel",
                        Context->{"testPackage`"}
                },
                {
                "Documentation", 
                    Resources->{"ReferencePages/Symbols/test"},
                    Language -> "English",
                    LinkBase->"testPackage"
                }
            }
]
```

(Compared to what Workbench creates, I added the `"Kernel"` extension, the `Resources` and the `LinkBase`)
But this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Make sure `PacletInfo.m` has [proper "Documentation" and "Kernel" `Extensions`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28349/14303). By default Workbench (at least version 2) creates `PacletInfo.m` file that doesn't have sufficient `Extensions` for *Mathematica* versions 9+.

Comment: @jkuczm I just tried that and edited the question, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Strange, I just created test project and it worked for me. Which operating system and *Mathematica* version are you using?

Comment: @jkuczm Hmm very strange, I tested once more, and when I load the package with `<< testPackage` ` it doesn't work, but when I load it with `Needs["testPackage`"] it does work, and any subsequent time I load it with `<< testPackage` ` it now does work, even in a new Mathematica session. This is in Mathematica 11, OSX. Anyway it does work now, so thanks :)

Comment: @jkuczm thanks for pointing me here.  It half-worked (`>>` worked, but not i-in-circle) initially, when I set up `PacletInfo.m` using the Eclipse text editor.  However, seeing that it only half worked, & did not sync correctly with Workbench's Paclet Info Editor, I cleaned it out and tried to recreate it with the Pactlet Info Editor.  That would not let me add `Kernel -> Context`.  So I went back to the text editor.  Now it does not work at all.  :(  Presumably there is some corrupt Eclipse state somewhere I need to clean out.  Mod that, and mod the i-in-circle, this seems to be the solution.

Comment: sorry, PEBKAC on my part.   The string in `Context->{}` _must_ end with a back-tic.  This gets me reliably back to the state where the `>>` link works.  Unfortunately, this does not seem to fix the i-in-a-circle icon from the function's hover box.  That link still does not work.  :/

Comment: @billc Sorry, I missed the fact that the this doesn't fix the i-in-a-circle issue. This question is not an exact duplicate of your question then. Maybe you could edit your original question mentioning that answer to this question only fixes the ">>" link issue, but not the second one, then we can try to reopen your question. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix the i-in-a-circle link.

Comment: @jkuczm ... turns out that part of the question is also a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125661/how-do-i-add-the-infobutton-in-autocomplete-that-links-to-the-documentation-page.  I added a link to it over on my question. I really wanna get an answer to this someday, so I just threw a bounty on it as well.  :D

Answer (score 3):

From the [comment by jkuczm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126147/linking-usage-message-to-package-documentation#comment341402_126147),

> Make sure `PacletInfo.m` has proper `"Documentation"` and `"Kernel"` Extensions.

Within the `"Kernel"` extension, set the `Context` to match your package context and name.

Further reading:

- [What is the purpose of the Kernel and Application extensions in PacletInfo.m?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130359/12)