# What is the purpose of the Kernel and Application extensions in PacletInfo.m?

Tags: documentation, workbench

Wolfram Workbench has a graphical editor for `PacletInfo.m` files.  It is possible to add a "Kernel" extension with `Symbols`, `Root` and `Context` keys.

What is the purpose of each of these?  Where is the documentation for this (if it exists)?

[image]

Sometimes it is also possible to add an Application extension with Root and Context keys:

[image]

It is not yet clear to me when the Workbench offers adding "Application" and when it offers "Kernel".  I believe I created a "Mathematica Application" in both cases, but I'm not yet experienced with the Workbench ...

What is the difference between them?

---

#### Partial answer

Based on [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28316/creating-cross-version-compatible-documentation-with-workbench/28349#comment90056_28316) by Teake Nutma, setting the "Context" allows usage message to have the little >> sign at the end.  Clicking it opens the Documentation Centre.  I tried this and it worked both in the Kernel and Application extensions (within two separate projects).

Comment: Related [comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28316/creating-cross-version-compatible-documentation-with-workbench/28349#comment90056_28316) re `Context`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tried it and setting `Context` either in `Kernel` or `Application` does cause the `>>` sign to appear at the end of the usage messages.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

This answer is now mostly superseded by:

- [PacletInfo.m documentation project](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132064/12)

---

I am not sure about the difference between `"Kernel"` and `"Application"`, but I was able to gather the following information:

Adding the `"Kernel"` extension to `PacletInfo.m` allows the paclet to provide a [package](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/packages.html) that is loadable with [`Needs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Needs.html). (I have not tried if `"Application"` works too).

In order for this to work, it seems to be necessary to set the `Context` and `Root` arguments, like so:

```
Paclet[
    Name -> "MyPack",
    Version -> "0.0.1",
    MathematicaVersion -> "10.0+",
    Description -> "My Mathematica Application",
    Creator -> "John Johnson",
    Extensions -> 
        {
            {"Kernel", Root -> ".", Context -> "MyPack`"}
        }
]
```

Effects of setting `` Context -> "MyPack`" ``:

- `` FindFile["MyPack`"] `` will resolve to the correct location so that the package can get loaded by `Needs` or `Get`.
- If the `"Documentation"` extension is also present, then symbol usage messages will get a little `>>` sign at the end.  Clicking it will open the correct documentation page.
- The value can also be a list of contexts.

Effects of setting `Root`:

- `` FindFile["MyPack`"] `` will search in the location that `Root` points to in the usual manner: it will resolve either to `init.m`, to `Kernel/init.m`, to `MyPack.m` (or I assume to the other usual possibilities such as `.mx` files within directories having names agreeing `$SystemID`—but I haven't tried this one)

  The usual setting would be `Root -> "."` when the package root coincides with the paclet root, but we can also put all the package files and an `init.m` in a subdirectory and point to that instead.

#### Further reading

- [How to distribute Mathematica packages as paclets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131101/12)

#### References

- https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink/
- [This comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28316/creating-cross-version-compatible-documentation-with-workbench/28349#comment90056_28316) by Teake Nutma
- [Workbench Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/reference/projects/pacletinfocontents.html)

Comment: Where can I find more information about what `Root -> "."` does?  Thanks

Comment: @QuantumDot I listed all my references ... the rest is experimentation.  If you find out more, let me know!  I just updated the answer.  I believe that it works like this: if we set Context to something, then `FindFile` with that context will first go to `Root`, then keep searching from there for `Contextname.m`, `init.m`, `Kernel/init.m` and perhaps other standard thing.  Sorry about responding late, I had to do a few more experiments.