# How do I activate the infobutton that links to the documentation page for package functions

Tags: front-end, documentation, button, autocomplete

When typing the name of a built-in function like Integrate, the button ([image]) appears next to that name in the autocomplete:

[image]

But in my self-defined application，it doesn't works

[image]

Also, the button is gray when I complete input:

[image]

the button should links to the page:"QuantumInformation/ref/GeneralizedGellMannMatrix"

[image]

(My enviroment is Windows 10, Mathematica 11.0, Wolfram Workbench 10.1.757)

Thanks.

Comment: Already asked but unfortunately no answers. [How do I add the infobutton in autocomplete that links to the documentation page for package functions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125661/5478) The short answer in related questions is "from time to time you can tweak it by finding appriopriate text resource but the state of art is that those features are not ready for customization by users".