# calling up workbench-generated help pages for custom functions

Tags: documentation, workbench

Using Wolfram Workbench 2, I have succeeded in creating custom documentation for custom functions.  After doing "Application Tools -> Deploy Application", I can `Get` my package, and then call up my function's documentation page via the right-click menu:

[image: custom docs accessible via right click]

Built-in functions have two nice additional ways of calling up docs – a small `>>` link that appears in the info box, and an i-in-a-circle icon in the function's hover box:

[image: builtin functions have other ways]

These two ways of accessing help pages are not available for my custom function:

[image: custom docs not accessible this way]

Is this a limitation of Workbench, or is there some way to activate these two additional ways of calling up function help?

I have found a few other questions which reference https://github.com/jmlopez-rod/ApplicationMaker , but I am not clear if that package is meant to supplement or replace Workbench.  Workbench on it's own already seems fairly complex, so I am hoping to find a solution which will not required (too much) additional tooling beyond Workbench itself.

Comment: This is actually a two part question.  Both parts are in fact duplicates, but of different questions.  The question cited above addresses the `>>` part.  This questions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125661/how-do-i-add-the-infobutton-in-autocomplete-that-links-to-the-documentation-page addresses the i-in-a-circle part, but at the moment has no answer.