# Sub-packages and auto-completion

Tags: packages, autocomplete

[*Cross-posted on Wolfram Community*](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1252133)

---

I have a Mathematica application that consists of two sub-packages, corresponding to the contexts `` foo` `` (`foo.m`) and `` foo`b` `` (`b.m`).  Some of the definitions in `foo.m` rely on functions in `b.m`. Therefore `b.m` must be loaded before `foo.m` in some way (there are multiple ways to achieve this).

If I do this, auto-completion will be available for `` foo` `` symbols, but not for `` foo`b` `` symbols.  Why?  How can I enable auto-completion for both sub-packages?  Actually, completion for `` foo`b` `` symbols works when requested explicitly with Command-K, but the completion window doesn't pop up automatically.

If the loading order is reversed, i.e. load `` foo` `` first, then `` foo`b` ``, then everything is fine.  But I cannot do that because of the dependency structure.

---

Here's the package source, for convenience: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6eoxumeqd42411/foo.zip?dl=0

The directory structure looks like this:

[image]

And here's the file contents:

```
(* init.m *)

Get["foo`b`"] (* Must be loaded first in some way because foo.m uses it. *)
Get["foo`foo`"]
```

```
(* foo.m *)

(* Normally, BeginPackage would refer to foo`b` in its second argument.
   Since in this basic example foo` doesn't actually use foo`b`, I removed
   this to demonstrate that the problem isn't caused by it. *)
BeginPackage["foo`" (* , {"foo`b`"} *)]

TheName::usage == "TheName[]";

Begin["`Private`"]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

```
(* b.m *)

BeginPackage["foo`b`"]

TheOtherName::usage == "TheOtherName[]";

Begin["`Private`"]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

If I load `` foo` `` (which in turn loads `` foo`b` `` as well, through `init.m`), `TheOtherName` is not offered for completion.

[image]

I need a solution where one sub-package can be dependent on the other, but auto-completion works for both.

---

If I change `init.m` to

```
Get["foo`foo`"]
Get["foo`b`"]
```

(i.e. I exchange the order of the two `Get` commands), then auto-completion works fine.

I do not want to do this because in my real use case, `` foo` `` depends on `` foo`b` ``, therefore `foo.m` would need to load `b.m` in some way.  A second `` Get["foo`b`"] `` after this would cause double-loading of `b.m`, which is ugly and slow.  These are large packages and the slowdown is actually noticeable on a Raspberry Pi.

If I use

```
Get["foo`b`"]
Get["foo`foo`"]
```

or

```
Get["foo`foo`"]
Needs["foo`b`"]
```

to prevent double-loading, then auto-completion is broken again.

I am hoping to find out what precisely in `` Get["foo`b`"] `` re-enables auto-completion and re-create that thing in isolation without actually re-evaluating all definitions from `b.m`.

Comment: @Kuba What I said was not correct. The problem isn't simply caused by `BeginPackage`.  It is somehow dependent on the loading order, or the creation order of the contexts.  My suspicion is that when the context ``foo` `` is created, all of its subcontexts are removed from auto-completion. Or something like that. I'm not sure.  I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: The only solution I could find so far was to factor out the dependencies into a third sub-package which won't be added to the `$ContextPath`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update, will take a closer look later. (deleting old comment)

Comment: Could you please show the results of     Context[TheName]    and 
    Context[TheOtherName]    ?

Comment: @WenChern The contexts are as expected: ``foo`TheName`` and ``foo`b`TheOtherName``.

Comment: I had an issue with this once (but which was for me from ``Internal`SymbolList[False]``) but ``FrontEnd`Private`GetUpdatedSymbolContexts`` seemed to cure it about ~50% of the time.

Comment: Actually never mind that was the reverse issue

Comment: I created "sub-packages" in this way, but found ```<<foo` ``` in a notebook does not make the public/exported symbols in the sub-packages ```<<foo`b` ``` such as `TheOtherName` usable in the notebook. I had to do  ```<<foo`; <<foo`b`;``` which seems counter-intuitive. Is it normal? Has the behavior changed in Mathematica 13 which is what I'm using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I can provide some clarification and a workaround

---

#### Clarification

First off, this only triggers on the `EndPackage`:

For example, this still allows `ggg` to autocomplete:

```
BeginPackage["foo`a`"];
ggg::usage = "asdasd";
EndPackage[];

(*Break this into different cells or the FE acts like EndPackage was called!*)
Abort[]
    
BeginPackage["foo`", {"foo`a`"}];
```

But the moment you call `EndPackage[]` `ggg` stops autocompleting.

Further investigation shows that even simply messing with the `$ContextPath` is enough to do it.

```
BeginPackage["foo`a`"];
ggg::usage = "asdasd";
EndPackage[];

(* again, split these into two cells *)

PrependTo[$ContextPath, "foo`"];
```

Next, this does not seem to have to do with the standard way the FE handles autocompletions (as I know it at least).

I say this because the following doesn't prevent it from auto-completing (working from a `Quit` kernel):

```
BeginPackage["foo`a`"];
ggg::usage = "asdasd";
EndPackage[];

FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`UpdateKernelSymbolContexts[
  "foo`",
  Join[
   {"foo`", "foo`a`"},
   $ContextPath
   ],
  {{"foo`", {"aaa"}, {}, {"aaa"}, {}}}
  ]
```

And even more to the point, this isn't enough to *preserve* the autocompletion:

```
BeginPackage["foo`a`"];
ggg::usage = "asdasd";
EndPackage[];

(* Split the cell here *)

Internal`SymbolList[False]

(* And further split here *)

BeginPackage["foo`"]; EndPackage[]

(* Make sure to call Internal`SymbolList[True] after trying this *)
```

why this happens is something I haven't been able to figure out. This behavior is a lot like the behavior involved in [developerFunctions.m](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151967/38205). There doesn't seem to be anything in `NeedCurrentFrontEndSymbolsPacket` to explain it.

---

#### Workaround

Since this triggers on `$ContextPath` edits, you simply need to edit the `$ContextPath` again.

This will recover the auto-completion:

```
BeginPackage["foo`a`"];
EndPackage[];
```

So after you load your packages, you can use that to get your autocompletions back.