# Missing Hover and Autocomplete INFO Buttons for Custom Paclet

Tags: packages, documentation, autocomplete, usage-messages, development

I've built my own paclet application with documentation using Workbench 3 (Eclipse add-in 10.1.822) with MM 12.1 (*there are currently issues with 12.2-3 and the only Workbench add-in update, which I'm not willing to risk yet*).  Workbench is creating the index file but the info button is missing on the auto-complete drop-down for my own functions.

[image]

I found this question [How do I add the infobutton in autocomplete that links to the documentation page for package functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125661/how-do-i-add-the-infobutton-in-autocomplete-that-links-to-the-documentation-page/246416#246416) from a few years ago and am very curious if there's been any progress on this.

In addition, while the hover button double-chevron correctly brings up the custom function's Usage statement, the info button is grayed out and does not link to my symbol documentation like the built-in functions do.

[image]

I have notice though, if I go ahead and evaluate this ?*function* line, it outputs the usage statement.  In the top right corner of the usage statement, there is an info button that is enabled and ***actually*** links to my symbol page!

[image]

This does show (I think) that the index is working to some limited degree and provides a work-around to getting to the desired ref/symbol page.  However, I'd ***really***, ***really*** like to get the hover button and auto-complete button working.  Has there been any progress on this issue?  Anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: I could never get this working. You might want to contact Wolfram Research and ask them to provide a supported and documented way to add that (i) button.

Comment: WRI sent back a rather useless response about it being undocumented as of yet.