# How to incorporate ResourceFunctions to autocomplete

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, tooltip, resourcefunction

**Edit**: As mentioned in the comments below, typing just ResourceFunction["Mo"] results in a list of ResourceFunctions that have a name that starts with Mo. This is good enough for me although it would be convenient if typing just Mo would show both official functions and resource functions (in another color).

I wonder if it is possible to use ToolTip, MouseOver and the likes in a way that, while writing, Mathematica proposes suggestions that incorporates ResourceFunctions rather than the current situation where it only shows official functions. Perhaps the resource functions can be colored in orange as a sort of warning that there is no guarantee that the function will work.

There is already a resource function that searches for other resource functions but it requires the Cloud and I would rather that Mathematica gives suggestions while typing.

Hence, I suppose this question has two parts:

How to get the list of all resource functions ? (Is it allowed to use web scraping to get that ? Maybe it can be extracted from the documentation center instead ?)

How to make a GUI interface that suggests elements in that list (ideally like Mathematica's autocomplete)?

Comment: When I type `ResourceFunction["` and then start a function name, I get autocomplete suggestions for all resource functions.  Does that happen for you?

Comment: @JasonB. Hello thank you I did not know that was a feature in some versions. I have Linux 13.1. I will mention my version in my question.

Comment: Do you get a result from `PacletObject["ResourceAutoCompletionData"]`?

Comment: @JasonB. Yes but when I clicked on the Packlet, in the description it says "Missing["NotAvailable"]"

Comment: Maybe Missing there means that the description is missing and not something about the paclet

Comment: Thank you for the edit.

Comment: I think it should be working for you now.  You have the paclet, the missing description is just because it is an internal paclet not a user-facing one.  When I type `ResourceFunction["` and then two letters like `Mo` then it starts autocompleting for me.  If it isn't working for you you may need to report it as a bug.

Comment: @JasonB. Thank you ! Now that i used 2  letters in ResourceFunction["  instead of 1 I can see the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another approach to get the autocompletion working:

```
$ContextPath = 
  DeleteDuplicates@Append[$ContextPath, "ResourceFunctions`"];

ResourceFunction;
If[Names[#] === {},
    ToExpression["ResourceFunctions`" <> #, StandardForm, 
     Function[s, s := ResourceFunction[#], HoldAll]]
    ] & /@ 
  FunctionResource`Autocomplete`Private`$resourceFunctionNames;

SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
 FixedPoint[
  Normal,
  Merge[Merge[Replace[{{a__Association} :> <|a|>, {___, l_} :> l}]]]@{
    GeneralUtilities`ToAssociations@
     Options[$FrontEndSession, AutoStyleOptions],
    <|AutoStyleOptions -> <|"SymbolContextStyles" -> \
<|"ResourceFunctions`" -> RGBColor[0.89, 0.37, 0.13]|>|>|>
    }
  ]
 ]
```

Effectively, this does the following:

1. Add the context `` ResourceFunctions` ``  to the `$ContextPath`
2. Go through the list of resource functions (`` FunctionResource`Autocomplete`Private`$resourceFunctionNames ``), and if the symbol doesn't already exist anywhere on the `$ContextPath`, add a new definition of the form `` ResourceFunctions`function = ResourceFunction["function"] ``
3. Set the `AutoStyleOptions` for the `` ResourceFunctions` ``  context to color the symbols orange

[image]

Comment: Is there an easy way to revert back to the usual autocomplete behavior after using the code you provided ? It works quite well in combination with this answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235055/86543 as it allows searching for resource functions using fuzzy search without having to open a browser. But, the code in this answer creates shadowing problems with hidden internal mathematica functions at times. Hence It would be nice if I could remove it when there are shadowing problems.

Comment: I am aware of the existence of the resource function that searches other resource functions but It requires wolfram cloud. I could also maybe set up a function using the code above for searching but I like the fuzzy search with autocomplete.

Comment: @userrandrand Can you give a concrete example of where this causes shadowing warnings? I had tried to add a (very basic) safeguard against this by checking if a symbol with that name already exists, so I assume you are loading other packages afterwards? That being said, you should be able to remove the modifications by doing ``Remove["ResourceFunctions`<name>"]``, where `<name>` is the name of the problematic resource function, or `*` if you want to remove all functions. If you want to fully reset everything, you can also remove the context from `$ContextPath`, but that's not strictly needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. That explains why I usually do not see any shadowing errors. I think one of the system/official mathematica functions I used called a native package and that created the shadowing problem.  I do not remember which function but if it happens again I will try to give a precise scenario where it happens.

Answer (score 3):

> As mentioned in the comments below, typing just `ResourceFunction["Mo"]` results in a list of `ResourceFunction`s that have a name that starts with Mo. This is good enough for me although it would be convenient if typing just Mo would show both official functions and resource functions (in another color).

You can install any `ResourceFunction` persistently so that it can be used like a built-in function using [`ResourceFunction["PersistResourceFunction"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PersistResourceFunction). For example, the following installs [`ResourceFunction["ShortInputForm"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ShortInputForm) persistently:

```
ResourceFunction["PersistResourceFunction"]["ShortInputForm"]
```

> [image: output]

Now typing "Sh" in an input cell opens the autocompletion menu:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Very nice ! That's quite convenient.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Alexey and Jason works. This resource function [ResourceFunctionInput](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ResourceFunctionInput/) also provides autocompletion but with a different design.

**Example** :

I opted for the default installation.

In that case type <kbd>esc</kbd> rfi <kbd>esc</kbd> as in the gif below then type directly the name of the resource function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for improving you answer (+1)