# Auto completion starting from anywhere in the name

Tags: front-end, autocomplete

**Edit:** After reading the last [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235055/86543) from the related question mentioned below I saw that it was all I needed.

**What I would like**

I would like to type Comp and automatically see auto complete suggestions from `Names["*Comp*"]`.

**Criteria**

I will accept any sorting of the suggestions including any default sorting by auto complete but it would be interesting if it could be sorted by usage frequency. For example using [`WolframLanguageData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html) like in one of the examples from the documentation :

```
data = DeleteCases[
   WolframLanguageData[
    All, {"Ranks", "CanonicalName"}], {_Missing, _}];
```

**Related question**

There was a similar question here: [Is it possible to improve Mathematica's auto-completion feature?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16599/is-it-possible-to-improve-mathematicas-auto-completion-feature).

But the answers there are designed to auto-complete LLP to `ListLinePlot` for example. I would like Plo to suggest also `ListLinePlot`.

**ResourceFunction that seems related**

[QueryCodeCompletion](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/QueryCodeCompletion/)

searches in Mathematica's auto-completion suggestions. I could maybe get what I want from there but i need to incorporate it to the front-end interface and I know little about coding in the front-end.

**Why ?**

Because it allows finding functions that are in the same category and not having to remember the order in names. For example I often forget where to put Boundary in [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion.html)