# How to get rid of a built-in context from autocomplete?

Tags: front-end, customization, autocomplete

I have noticed that when I type the name of built-in function `Limit` in *Mathematica*, the autocomplete suggests two variants at the top: the first one is the working one, and the second one is just context `` Limit` ``. How can I remove the latter from the autocomplete list? Why was it created in the first place?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I asked a question about that ``Limit` `` before, and it got closed. I doubt you can get an answer.

Comment: Cab you post the exact code you have used to create this problem?

Comment: @bills I have not created  the problem, when I opened Mathematica today I found this other Limit "function" which was useless... so I want to know how to remove it since it was not there previously.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah sorry, my mistake. What does context mean? Why was it added in the first place? How do I remove it? Since it wasn't previously there.

Comment: A context is roughly equivalent to a namespace in c++. It is a way to prevent name collisions while grouping common functionality together. What you are seeing is that when you used `Limit` for the first time, its underlying functionality was loaded into ``Limit` ``. This happens with a lot of built-in functionality.

Comment: @rcollyer Can I get rid of it?

Comment: I've made the title more specific, feel free to roll back if the intent is wrong.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @user372003 not that I'm aware of. Also, in some cases it can be useful as you don't have to write out the entire context.

Comment: Contexts are described beginning with the 8th tutorial in [this overview of symbol names](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThingsOverview.html).

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6842/4999 -- I don't know if the answer can be modified to suit your desires, though.  The function that is modified still exists.

Comment: I have this same issue for FullSimplify. I know why this issue comes up, because I used to type FullSimplify often in hurry, ending up typing FullSI with a tab. This created the FullSI autoprompt. How do I remove it?